# Updating record in Laravel from a select using laravel's lists not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In one of my laravel pages I am updating a record. The form is bound to the model, and all fields are updating properly except those where I am presenting a select using lists that populates the select from the database:

`{{ Form::select('resume_id', $resume_lists) }}`

I just have no idea why these will not update. They are pulling the appropriate values from mySQL. Any ideas?

Thank you.

I have my code in routes, not in a controller

```
Route::get('application/edit/{id}', array('as' => 'application.edit',    function($id) 
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $company_lists = Company::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get()->lists('company', 'id');
    $resume_lists = Resume::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get()->lists('name', 'id');   //changed resume to name
    $companies = Company::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get(); //just added
    //$currentintdate=$application['followupBy'];  /////
    Session::put('appid', $id); /////

    return View::make('application-edit', array('company_lists' => $company_lists), array('resume_lists' => $resume_lists)) 
        ->with('application', Application::find($id));
}));
```

Comment: Can you show us the code from your controller?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$resume_lists = YourResumeModel::lists('title', 'id');

{{ Form::select('resume_id', $resume_lists) }}
```

frist column is your text for dropdown
and next column is your row id

Comment: I will try this thank you. The same code that creates the record will not update the record for those columns...the columns that are using laravel/eloquent selects. Using regular selects this works but I was trying to use Laravel with form mode binding. Otherwise I guess I have to use pure SQL to populate the select

Answer (score 0):

just var dump the resume list data in controller, make sure its available at the controller, so after you initialize the variable/array

```
return var_dump($resume_lists); // check if its valid array with id as key and label as value, if available, go view and do the same
```

Comment: this was helpful to know. however, it does return the array and it has all the right values. it just will not update the record. I think I'm missing something stupid but it happens for updates whenever I am using _lists

Answer (score 0):

Use: `$resume_lists = Resume::all()->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->lists('name', 'id');`

Or: `$resume_lists = Resume::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->lists('name', 'id')->toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

well, my records were not updating because I had a column as not nullable and I was not passing any value while testing. I got no error at all about this so I had no idea.